# SES rule to only allow mail to a specific domain

Tags: amazon-ses

Is it possible to configure SES to only send mails to certain domains?

I'm having problems finding such a feature in the AWS documentation.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same requirement

Comment: @Ralph Nope, but I ought to get back to it. Pretty much the least interesting thing on my plate, though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by configuring appropriate IAM policies you will be able to restrict e-mail sending to certain domains and recipient emails.

Configure the policy on the account or group of the SES IAM user that sends the e-mails

A sample excerpt is below.

```json
    {
      "Version":"2012-10-17",
      "Statement":[
        {
          "Effect":"Allow",
          "Action":[
            "ses:SendEmail",
            "ses:SendRawEmail"
          ],
          "Resource":"*",
          "Condition":{
            "ForAllValues:StringLike":{
              "ses:Recipients":[
                "*@example.com"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Additionally, you can restrict the emails on `fromAddress`, `FromDisplaynames`, etc.

Reference : [SES Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/control-user-access.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [Knowledge center article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/block-email-domain-ses/) to block emails from specific domains or email addresses in Amazon SES and also you can use Recipient-based control using receipt rules. To know more, Kindly [refer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-concepts.html#receiving-email-concepts-rules)